# Are these cut lines?

Tags: cad, technical-drawing, drafting, drawings

In [the following drawing](http://www.digipeer.de/index.php?media=DMA_FA_014_20728&size=2) I am looking at the lined that come in on either side of the teeth/tabs that are spaced 9 mm apart and extend 6 mm into the material.

[image]

In my head these are cut or shear lines between alternating teeth/tabs.  Short ones ben up slightly and the long ones bed down slightly.  However there is no side view to confirm this.  The material is 0.8 mm thick.  The title according to google translate is "Locking Plate" in english.

When I leave the lines open like in the drawing I windup with just a solid piece.  The extended lines disappear.

[image]

**Would it be a reasonable assumption to make a 0.1 slice where those lines go in and then partially bend the teeth/tab alternating up and down?**

Comment: According to the draiwng, I would think so, but where did the 3D model come from?

Comment: @DKNguyen I drew the 3D model.  demonstrating what I had attempted so far and that leaving the lines open just made for a solid piece.  I do not think my 3D model as it stands currently is correct.  I just wanted to check my thoughts before proceeding

Comment: they look like cut lines, but as to bending upwards who can say?

Comment: I suppose one could also twist tabs, but then why have short and long?

Comment: You can't really explain why short and long without seeing what it goes into. For all you know, it could be an overhead view of the part after it has been punched and bent, and half the tabs could be bent up and the other half down, or half flat and half up, or half flat and half down. Can't really tell.

Comment: @DKNguyen As I make my way through the drawing set I will see if I spot the assembly drawing and if so I will update this question

Comment: That could be the part as cut in this process step only. In a subsequent operation it could have tabs bent or they might be bent when the part is pressed into an assembly - a one-way operation that make it difficult to remove the part.

Comment: @Transistor I had not considered that they would be "Adjusted" in a later stage.  Thank you for opening my eyes to this possibility.

Comment: There is no bent-up otherwise there should be root lines at the bases to indicate this.

Comment: this may help ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=sicherungsblech&iax=images&ia=images

Comment: Is there another, higher level, drawing that shows how this part fits into an assembly?  If so, it might find a side view or section.

Comment: I have not yet found the assembly drawing, but I am making my way through them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, that could be the part as cut in this process step only. In a subsequent operation it could have tabs bent or they might be bent when the part is pressed into an assembly - a one-way operation that would make it difficult to remove the part.

Comment: I agree they are likely shear lines, and the bending has not yet happened